# Seeking "redo selection" or "undo clear selection" in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, select, undo-redo

Is there a "redo selection" or "undo clear selection" in ArcGIS Pro?

I'm wanting to be able to basically undo a clear selection, so that a selection that I've cleared comes back. It's a real sore when you have a good amount of features selected, then you happen to click off of it, and you can't get that same selection back, unless you do it all over again.

Answer (score 1):

Although you cannot go back to a previous selection, (without doing the select operation again), you can make a temporary in-map subset from your selection so that you don't lose those features you selected.  Do so by: Right Click on layer->Selection->Make Layer From Selected Features.